# Set selected value in dropdownlist from MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am binding a dropdownlist using the below code

Model

```
public IEnumerable<TitleNew> TitleOption =
    new List<TitleNew>
    {
        new TitleNew {Id = 0, Value = "---Select---"},
        new TitleNew {Id = 1, Value = "Mr."},
        new TitleNew {Id = 2, Value = "Ms."}
    };

public class TitleNew
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
public string Title { get; set; }
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Title,
                                 new SelectList(Model.TitleOption,
                                "Id", "Value",
                                 Model.TitleOption.First().Id))
```

I was unable to set the selected value to dropdownlist. The selected value comes from the database and it sets for Title property.
Please help me out.

Comment: use viewbag instead of model.

Comment: (1) Remove `new TitleNew {Id = 0, Value = "---Select---"},` from you code and use an overload of `DropDownListFor()` that accepts a `labelOption`. (2) Its the value of `Title` which determines what is selected and the 4th parameter of the `SelectList` constructor is ignored when you binding to a property so remove `Model.TitleOption.First().Id` (3) set the value of `Title` to `2` before you pass the model to the view and `"Ms."` will be selected

Answer (score 1):

`new TitleNew {Id = 0, Value = "---Select---"}` looks like an option label, which is already included in an overloaded method for `dropdownlistfor`.

So if you want that to be the option that all users first see when they look at the dropdownlist then this should work:

```
public IEnumerable<TitleNew> TitleOption =
new List<TitleNew>
{
    new TitleNew {Id = 0, Value = "Mr."},
    new TitleNew {Id = 1, Value = "Ms."}
};

public class TitleNew
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
public string Title { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Title, new SelectList(Model.TitleOption, "Id", "Value"), "-- Select -- ")
```